# Ratiobutton default value in a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add a radiobutton that have a default value on my gui (switching between 'digital' and 'analog'). The following code displays with default value = 'digital' shown on the buttons.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text = 'MPD').grid(row = 1, column = 15)
MPDmode = tk.Frame(root)
MPDmode.grid(row = 2, column = 15)
MPDmode_var = tk.StringVar(value = 'digital')
MPDdigital = tk.Radiobutton(MPDmode, text = 'Digital', variable = MPDmode_var, indicatoron = False, value = 'digital', width = 8)
MPDanalog = tk.Radiobutton(MPDmode, text = 'Analog', variable = MPDmode_var, indicatoron = False, value = 'analog', width = 8)
MPDdigital.grid(row = 0)
MPDanalog.grid(row = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

However, if I define the content in a function, the default value cannot be shown. ie:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def start():
    tk.Label(root, text = 'MPD').grid(row = 1, column = 15)
    MPDmode = tk.Frame(root)
    MPDmode.grid(row = 2, column = 15)
    MPDmode_var = tk.StringVar(value = 'digital')
    MPDdigital = tk.Radiobutton(MPDmode, text = 'Digital', variable = MPDmode_var, indicatoron = False, value = 'digital', width = 8)
    MPDanalog = tk.Radiobutton(MPDmode, text = 'Analog', variable = MPDmode_var, indicatoron = False, value = 'analog', width = 8)
    MPDdigital.grid(row = 0)
    MPDanalog.grid(row = 1)

root = tk.Tk()
start()
root.mainloop()
```

Because I want to make my project development more structure, I want to put the contents in a function and call it at different locations in the code to build the GUI. May I know how I can achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `StringVar` got GCed when created in a function. You can create the `StringVar` as a global variable:

```
def start():
    global MPDmode_var
    ...
    MPDmode_var = tk.StringVar(value = 'digital')
```

But if you are looking for better structure, you can use a class instead:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Start(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,**kwargs)
        tk.Label(master, text = 'MPD').grid(row = 1, column = 15)
        self.grid(row = 2, column = 15)
        self.MPDmode_var = tk.StringVar(value='digital')
        MPDdigital = tk.Radiobutton(self, text = 'Digital', variable = self.MPDmode_var,
                                    indicatoron = False, value = 'digital', width = 8)
        MPDanalog = tk.Radiobutton(self, text = 'Analog', variable = self.MPDmode_var,
                                   indicatoron = False, value = 'analog', width = 8)
        MPDdigital.grid(row = 0)
        MPDanalog.grid(row = 1)

root = tk.Tk()
Start(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. I wonder how you know that the StringVar got GCed. Is there any debugging technique on that?

Comment: It is natural for local variables to be GCed after a function returns. The same goes for images defined in a function - you need to hold them in a global container (list, dict..) for them to show up properly.